# Octomap update frequency

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently we have already integrated the 2d hector_slam (which uses 2d laser range finder and provides tf information for the Octomap) and 3d ocotomap (in which the point cloud was provided by ASUS Xtion). But the update frequency of Octomap is pretty low.

```
    I used $ rostopic hz /octomap_full  to get the octomap update frequency, the following are some of the output:
```

subscribed to [/octomap_full]
average rate: 0.176
min: 5.684s max: 5.684s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.188
min: 4.961s max: 5.684s std dev: 0.36167s window: 3
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.182
min: 4.961s max: 5.842s std dev: 0.38378s window: 4
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.179
min: 4.961s max: 5.842s std dev: 0.36321s window: 5
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.181

```
     How to increase the octomap update frequency? 
     
     Highly appreciate your time and help!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199086/octomap-update-frequency/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the octomap server at 100% CPU? The actual octomap integration might just be the bottleneck.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0